# Error en consulta SQLite de Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sql

Quiero hacer una consulta del `id_empresa` de la tabla `TABLE_CLIENTE`, donde el nombre_cliente sea igual a lo que se inserta en el textView llamado `et_searchClient`, realizando la consulta DENTRO del activity.

Ya probé con varios métodos como hacer la búsqueda directo desde la base de datos y no sale bien, este es mi código actual:

Activity:

```
public class ListaEmpresas extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    ArrayList<Notas> listaNotas;
    RecyclerAdaptador recyclerAdaptador;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private Context mContext;
    private ImageView logoImage;
    private ListView clientsList;
    private Button btnInspeccion;
    private EditText et_searchClient;
    private TextView textView;
    ArrayList<String> clientList;
    ArrayAdapter adaptador;
    DatabaseHelper dbconeccion;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_empresas);
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mActivity = ListaEmpresas.this;
        clientsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clientsList);
        logoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileLogo);
        btnInspeccion = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInspeccion);
        //TextView para la impresión de los campos de la base de datos
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        et_searchClient = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_searchClient);
        dbconeccion = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        if(!SaveSharedPreference.getStringKeyValue(this, SaveSharedPreference.KEY_ORGANIZATION_IMAGE_PATH).equals("")){
            Bitmap b = SaveSharedPreference.loadImageFromStorage(SaveSharedPreference.getStringKeyValue(this, SaveSharedPreference.KEY_ORGANIZATION_IMAGE_PATH), SaveSharedPreference.ORGANIZATION_NAME);
            if(b != null){
                logoImage.setImageBitmap(b);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnInspeccion:
                SQLiteDatabase search = dbconeccion.getWritableDatabase();
                String codigo = et_searchClient.getText().toString();
                //Búsqueda RAWQUERY, quitarle el comentario a las lineas 109, 110, 116, 118, 120122, 123
                Cursor cursor = search.rawQuery("select id_cliente from TABLE_CLIENTE where nombre_cliente ='" +codigo+"'", null);
                try {
                    if (!codigo.isEmpty()) {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                            textView.setText(cursor.getString(1));

                            //INTENT QUE FUNCIONA

                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, select_form.class);

                            intent.putExtra("textView", textView.getText().toString());

                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No ha elegido ningún cliente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No existe ningún usuario con ese nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.e("BD", "ERROR AL CONECTAR CON LA BD");
                }
                search.close();
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
}
```

Base de datos:

```
public class DatabaseHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {super(context, Util.DATABASE_NAME, null, 1); }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_USUARIO   + "  (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,id_user STRING, nombre_user STRING, direccion STRING, telefono STRING, email STRING, id_empresa STRING, nombre_empresa STRING, rol_user STRING)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_ZONA      + "  (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,id_zona STRING, nombre_zona STRING, id_user STRING, desc_zona STRING)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_CLIENTE   + "  (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,id_cliente STRING, id_empresa STRING, id_zona STRING, nombre_cliente STRING, direccion STRING, telefono STRING, correo STRING, latitud STRING, longitud STRING)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_FORMS + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id_form STRING, id_user STRING, id_empresa STRING, form STRING)");// campos para almacenar los formularios
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_QUESTIONS + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id_question STRING, id_form STRING, question STRING, required STRING)");//tabla de almacenamiento de preguntas de los formularios
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_ANSWERS + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id_answer STRING, id_question STRING, answer STRING, id_answer_type STRING)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_ATRIBUTES + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id_attribute STRING, attribute STRING, type NUMBER, value STRING)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_USUARIO);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_ZONA);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_CLIENTE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean resetAllDataWithNoInfoSync() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_USUARIO);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_ZONA);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "  + Util.TABLE_CLIENTE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_ATRIBUTES);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_ANSWERS);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_QUESTIONS);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Util.TABLE_FORMS);
            onCreate(db);
        }
        finally {
            db.close();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean insertUsuario(  ArrayList<Usuario> dats) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            for (final Usuario user : dats) {
                String a =  "'"+user.getId_usuario() + "', '"+user.getNombre()+"' ,'"+user.getDireccion()+"', '"+ user.getTelefono() +"' , '"+ user.getCorreo()+"' , '"+ user.getId_empresa()+"' , '"+ user.getNombre_empresa()+"' , '"+ user.getRolUser()+"'" ;
                String values = " values ("+ a +" )";
                String g = "insert into " + Util.TABLE_USUARIO + " (id_user, nombre_user, direccion, telefono, email, id_empresa, nombre_empresa, rol_user)" + values;
                // Log.i("INSERTSQuiz",g);
                db.execSQL(g);
            }
        }catch ( Exception ex   ){
            Log.d("SAG ERROR",ex.getMessage() );
        }
        finally {
            db.close();
        }
        return  true;
    }

    public Cursor readZonaData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] nameDescZona = new String[] {
                "_id",
                "nombre_zona",
                "desc_zona"
        };
        Cursor c = db.query(Util.TABLE_ZONA, nameDescZona, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

}
```

Clase Util:

```
public class Util {
    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db";
    public static String TABLE_USUARIO = "usuario";
    public static String TABLE_ZONA = "zona";
    public static String TABLE_CLIENTE = "cliente";
    public static String TABLE_FORMS = "form";//Tabla de los formularios
    public static String TABLE_QUESTIONS = "questions";// tabla de los cuestionarios
    public static String TABLE_ANSWERS = "answers";// tabla de respuestas
    public static String TABLE_ATRIBUTES = "atributes";

    //public static final String URL_TARGET = "http://192.168.100.34/oauth/"; ESTE YA ESTABACOMENTADO
    public static final String URL_TARGET = "http://ec2-13-58-155-97.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/oauth/";
    //public static final String URL_TARGET = "http://ec2-13-58-155-97.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/administration/organizations/clients";  YO PUSE ESTA, ESTÁ MAL
}
```

Y estos son los errores que me manda, el cual al parecer es en la consulta:

```
08-27 11:31:52.008 14721-14721/mx.com.stesso.appstesso D/ERROR: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: insert into answersid_answers, id_question, answer, id_answer_typevalues (11', '11', 'q11respuesta11(hora)', '14)
08-27 11:31:52.015 14721-14721/mx.com.stesso.appstesso E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ",": syntax error
08-27 11:31:52.015 14721-14721/mx.com.stesso.appstesso D/ERROR: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: insert into answersid_answers, id_question, answer, id_answer_typevalues (12', '12', 'q12respuesta12(fechaHora)', '15)
```

Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Saludos bro, bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero que vayas por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio, de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. El error que tienes: `D/ERROR: near ","` significa que hay algo en tu cadena de texto que tiene una `coma`, la cual genera el error, revisa el valor que le estás pasando.

Comment: Gracias, soy nueva en android y me está costando mucho trabajo, pero lo voy a revisar

Comment: De nada, descuida, aquí todos aprendemos y colaboramos con el crecimiento de todos :D Revisa estos tutoriales: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/index.htm y https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/index.htm y en caso el inglés sea una barrera, dale una patada espartana con http://www.deepl.com/translator o aprende con http://www.duolingo.com - http://www.memrise.com http://www.engvid.com o en el super canal "ingles 123" de YouTube. Saludos :D

Comment: Gracias por los tutoriales, voy a revisarlos a fondo

Comment: de nada hermanita, estamos para servir, dale, estudia y a seguir elevando ese cosmos con todo el power 2.0!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías revisar la construcción la cadena de la consulta, parece que el error estaría en la falta de paréntesis, por eso te da el error con la coma, porque el parser espera encontrar el nombre de una tabla, encontrando primero una coma:

insert into **answersid_answers**, id_question, answer, **id_answer_typevalues** ('12', '12', 'q12respuesta12(fechaHora)', '15')

Tu consulta no está siendo construida correctamente. Una consulta correcta sería:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (
 column1,
 column2 ,..)
VALUES
(
 value1,
 value2 ,...);
```

En tu caso debería ser:

```
 insert into answers (id_answers, id_question, answer, id_answer_type ) values (12', '12', 'q12respuesta12(fechaHora)', '15)
```

**Añado**

Vigila también las comillas en los datos, en el error se observa también que te faltan comillas en los datos. Si no corriges esto también te dará error. Repasa bien el constructor de la consulta.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, no lo noté antes, ahora ya solo me marca error en la consulta del Activity :D, muchas gracias en serio

Comment: ¿Ves hermanita que todos nos apoyamos? Si esta respuesta resolvió tu pregunta, márcala como aceptada haciendo click en el check verde del lado izquierdo :D